# Creating a Class that creates array of Int with elements between two args(intStart, intEnd)

Tags: arrays, kotlin, logic

Hi everybody and thanks for your time!
I have an issue here. In a nutshell, i want to create a class an instance of which stores a data between two arguments of this class. Similar to "IntRange" class works.
For instance: val r1 = IntRange(0,5) // output 0 1 2 3 4 5.
Tried to explain as much as possible, English is not mouther tongue :)
What i've tried:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ownArray = OwnIntRange(0,2).getNumbers()
    
}

public interface Counter{
    fun getNumbers(): Array<Int>
    var counter: Int
}

class OwnIntRange(val intMin: Int, val intMax: Int): Counter{
    override var counter = 0
    override fun getNumbers(): Array<Int> {

        for (number in intMin..intMax){
            getNumbers()[counter] = number
            counter++
        }
        return getNumbers()
    }
}

//result: StackOverflowError
```

if you could correct my approach i would be really happy. Any critics welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `getNumbers()` function always calls itself at least once.  Which calls itself.  Which calls itself.  Which calls itself…  So it gets stuck in an endless series of nested calls, and runs out of stack space to store them.

[Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) *can* be a valid technique, but you always need a termination condition, a point beyond which it *stops* calling itself and starts returning — which your code doesn't have.  However, recursion isn't needed at all in this case.

I can't quite follow your intent in that implementation, but here's slightly different one that works:

```
override fun getNumbers(): Array<Int> {
    val a = Array<Int>(intMax - intMin + 1){ 0 }

    for (number in intMin..intMax)
        a[number - intMin] = number

    return a
}
```

(Note that this doesn't use `counter`; it looks like that's not needed at all.)

That that could be written much more simply (and slightly more efficiently), by making better use of the `init` parameter to the [`Array` constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/-init-.html):

```
override fun getNumbers() = Array(intMax - intMin + 1){
    it + intMin
}
```

It's also not common (and arguably [not a good idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Disadvantages)) to include the type in your variable names; simply calling them e.g. `min` and `max` would be simpler and easier to read.  (It also wouldn't need renaming if you changed the type from `Int` to `Long` or whatever.)

Of course, in production code you probably wouldn't need this class at all, as `IntRange` would do fine.  If you *did* need your own class, I'd look very seriously at whether a `getNumbers()` method was really needed, as there would almost certainly be better approaches that didn't create temporary arrays, e.g. by using the visitor pattern.

Comment: Now I got it! Thanks a lot. Your answer is amazing and covers all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8

```
override fun getNumbers(intMin: Int, intMax: Int): IntArray {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(intMin,intMax).toArray()
}
```

or

```
override fun getNumbers(intMin: Int, intMax: Int): List<Int> {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(intMin,intMax).toList()
    }
```

rangeClosed -> Returns a sequential ordered IntStream from startInclusive (inclusive) to endInclusive (inclusive) by an incremental step of 1.

```
public static IntStream rangeClosed(int startInclusive, int endInclusive)
```